# wasn't there a way to generate an event handler from the XAML editor in a silverlight project

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Not wanting to enter into the debate of wiring up event handlers in code or in XAML, sufice it to say, that I seem to recall there was a kind of "tab to create" feature in the XAML editor for silverlight projects.  Clearly it's been a while since I have been codeing XAML, but I was sure it was a simple process of adding an event handler in the code behind file for a control on the XAML page.

Can somebody tell me if I'm dreaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know for a fact you can use that feature when creating silverlight 2 projects.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate because it's a feature that has gone missing in my VS istallation, and I wonder why.

Comment: What version of VS?  I am using VS 2008 with SP 1.

Answer (score 0):

Reapplying Visual Stduio 2008 SP1 corrected the issue -- go figure.